# Rewrite hypothesis in Coq, keeping implication

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm doing a Coq proof. I have `P -> Q` as a hypothesis, and `(P -> Q) -> (~Q -> ~P)` as a lemma. How can I transform the hypothesis into `~Q -> ~P`?

When I try to `apply` it, I just spawn new subgoals, which isn't helpful.

Put another way, I wish to start with:

```
P : Prop
Q : Prop
H : P -> Q
```

and end up with

```
P : Prop
Q : Prop
H : ~Q -> ~P
```

given the lemma above - i.e. `(P -> Q) -> (~Q -> ~P)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as elegant as just an `apply`, but you can use `pose proof (lemma _ _ H) as H0`, where `lemma` is the name of your lemma. This will add another hypothesis with the correct type to the context, with the name `H0`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one case where ssreflect views do help:

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect.

Variable (P Q : Prop).
Axiom u : (P -> Q) -> (~Q -> ~P).

Lemma test (H : P -> Q) : False.
Proof. move/u in H. Abort.
```

`apply u in H` does also work, however it is too smart for its own good and does too much.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to transform `H` *in place* I would go with @ejgallego's answer, since SSReflect is now (starting from Coq 8.7.0) a part of standard Coq, but here is another option:

```
Ltac dumb_apply_in f H := generalize (f H); clear H; intros H.

Tactic Notation "dumb" "apply" constr(f) "in" hyp(H) := dumb_apply_in f H.
```

A simple test:

```
Variable (P Q : Prop).
Axiom u : (P -> Q) -> (~Q -> ~P).

Lemma test (H : P -> Q) : False.
Proof. dumb apply u in H. Abort.
```