# Modus Ponens and Modus Tollens in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

I would like to have Ltac tactics for these simple inference rules.

In Modus Ponens, if I have `H:P->Q`and `H1:P`, `Ltac mp H H1` will add `Q`to the context as `H2 : Q`.

In Modus Tollens, if I have `H:P->Q`and `H1:~Q`, then `Ltac mt H H1` will add `H2:~P`to the context.

I have written one for the modus ponens, but it does not work in the complicated cases where the precedent is also an implication.

`Ltac mp H0 H1 :=
let H := fresh "H" in
apply H0 in H1 as H.`

Edit : I have found the answer to Modus Ponens in another seemingly unrelated question ([Rewrite hypothesis in Coq, keeping implication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520531/rewrite-hypothesis-in-coq-keeping-implication)), where a "dumbed-down" version of `apply`is made with `generalize`.

`Ltac mp H H0 := 
let H1 := fresh "H" in
generalize (H H0); intros H1.`

I would still appreciate an answer for Modus Tollens, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
Ltac mt PtoQ notQ notP :=
  match type of PtoQ with
  | ?P -> _ => pose proof ((fun p => notQ (PtoQ p)) : ~ P) as notP
  end.
```

This tactic asks the user for the two input hypothesis and for an explicit name of the output hypothesis. I use `type of PtoQ` construction to extract the type `P` from the input implication and then provide an explicit term `(fun p => notQ (PtoQ p)` of type `P -> False`, which is definitionally equal to `~ P`. The explicit type ascription `: ~ P` is used to make the context look prettier, without it Coq would show the output hypothesis's type as `P -> False`.

Incidentally, I would use something like this to implement the modus ponens tactic:

```
Ltac mp PtoQ P Q := 
  pose proof (PtoQ P) as Q.
```

Here, again `PtoQ` and `P` parameters are the names of the input hypotheses and `Q` is the name to be added to the context.

Comment: Thank you! By mostly trial and error I have found that also
" 
Ltac mt H H0 :=
  let H1 := fresh "H" in
match type of H with
| ?A -> ?B => assert (~A) ; [intro H1 |] ; [contradiction H | ] end.
"
works.

Comment: No problem :) I started with a solution much like the one you mentioned, but I personally find that composition of `notQ` and `PtoQ` is a bit easier to follow. And  an anonymous function makes it impossible to forget about the need of a fresh variable.

Comment: I have just found that this doesn't work in the less obvious case where the implication is "P -> notQ" and the hypothesis is "Q". Do you have any idea how to make it more general ?

Comment: I would not call that case completely obvious, because in case of `P -> ~Q` you would need to use `~ ~ Q`. Note that `Q` and `~ ~ Q` are not equivalent in the constructivist setting of Coq. But for this particular case `Ltac mt' PtoQ notQ notP :=
  match type of PtoQ with | ?P -> _ => assert (~ P) as notP by tauto end.` should do the job

Comment: How would I "enforce" this equivalence ? The tactic returns `~ ~ Q` in the context which I cannot use with my other tactics.

Comment: (1) You need the `classical` axiom from [Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop.html) or an equivalent one. (2) Which tactic do you mean? Can you give a concrete example with `~ ~ Q` as the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182296/discussion-between-mlg556-and-anton-trunov).