# even_Sn_not_even_n - apply 1 hypothesis in another

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Unfortunately I got stuck again:

```
Inductive even : nat > Prop :=
| ev_0 : even 0
| ev_SS (n : nat) (H : even n) : even (S (S n)).

Lemma even_Sn_not_even_n : forall n,
    even (S n) <-> not (even n).
Proof.
  intros n. split.
  + intros H. unfold not. intros H1. induction H1 as [|n' E' IHn].
    - inversion H.
    - inversion_clear H. apply IHn in H0. apply H0.
  + intros H. induction n as [|n' IHn].
    - exfalso. apply H. apply ev_0.
    - apply evSS_inv'.
```

Here is the result:

```
1 subgoal (ID 179)

n' : nat
H : ~ even (S n')
IHn : ~ even n' -> even (S n')
============================
even n'
```

As far I could prove it in words:

(n' + 1) is not even according to H. Therefore according to IHn, it is not true that n' is not even (double negation):

```
IHn : ~ ~ even n'
```

Unfolding double negation, we conclude that n' is even.

But how to write it in coq?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to strip double negation is to introduce the "excluded middle" axiom, which is defined under the name `classic` in [`Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop.html), and apply the lemma `NNPP`.

However, in this particular case, you can use the technique called **reflection** by showing that the Prop is consistent with a boolean function (you might remember the `evenb` function introduced earlier in the book).

(Assuming you're at the beginning of IndProp) You'll soon see the following definition later in that chapter:

```
Inductive reflect (P : Prop) : bool -> Prop :=
| ReflectT (H : P) : reflect P true
| ReflectF (H : ~ P) : reflect P false.
```

You can prove the statement

```
Lemma even_reflect : forall n : nat, reflect (even n) (evenb n).
```

and then use it to move between a Prop and a boolean (which contain the same information i.e. the (non-)evenness of `n`) at the same time. This also means that you can do classical reasoning on that particular property without using the `classic` axiom.

I suggest to complete the exercises under Reflection section in IndProp, and then try the following exercises. (**Edit:** I uploaded the full answer [here](https://github.com/Bubbler-4/coq-misc-works/blob/gitpod-vnc/StackOverflow/even_reflect.v).)

```
(* Since `evenb` has a nontrivial recursion structure, you need the following lemma: *)
Lemma nat_ind2 :
  forall P : nat -> Prop,
  P 0 -> P 1 -> (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S (S n))) -> forall n : nat, P n.
Proof. fix IH 5. intros. destruct n as [| [| ]]; auto.
  apply H1. apply IH; auto. Qed.

(* This is covered in an earlier chapter *)
Lemma negb_involutive : forall x : bool, negb (negb x) = x.
Proof. intros []; auto. Qed.

(* This one too. *)
Lemma evenb_S : forall n : nat, evenb (S n) = negb (evenb n).
Proof. induction n.
  - auto.
  - rewrite IHn. simpl. destruct (evenb n); auto. Qed.

(* Exercises. *)
Lemma evenb_even : forall n : nat, evenb n = true -> even n.
Proof. induction n using nat_ind2.
  (* Fill in here *) Admitted.

Lemma evenb_odd : forall n : nat, evenb n = false -> ~ (even n).
Proof. induction n using nat_ind2.
  (* Fill in here *) Admitted.

Lemma even_reflect : forall n : nat, reflect (even n) (evenb n).
Proof. (* Fill in here. Hint: You don't need induction. *) Admitted.

Lemma even_iff_evenb : forall n, even n <-> evenb n = true.
Proof. (* Fill in here. Hint: use `reflect_iff` from IndProp. *) Admitted.

Theorem reflect_iff_false : forall P b, reflect P b -> (~ P <-> b = false).
Proof. (* Fill in here. *) Admitted.

Lemma n_even_iff_evenb : forall n, ~ (even n) <-> evenb n = false.
Proof. (* Fill in here. *) Admitted.

Lemma even_Sn_not_even_n : forall n,
    even (S n) <-> not (even n).
Proof. (* Fill in here.
  Hint: Now you can convert all the (non-)evenness properties to booleans,
  and then work with boolean logic! *) Admitted.
```

Comment: How can I get `~ ~ even n'` from H and IHn?

Comment: Seems, that we'll need Modus Tollens tactics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935508/modus-ponens-and-modus-tollens-in-coq.

Comment: `apply H in IHn.` gives incorrect conclusion: 2 subgoals to prove.

Comment: @user4035 Where are you stuck? I can share the proofs if you want. It's possible to complete all the proofs using only the basic tactics covered in the book.

Comment: "Where are you stuck?" - how to get `~ ~ even n'` from H and IHn?

Comment: "I can share the proofs if you want." - I'll try to complete as much as I can myself. Thanks.

Comment: @user4035 I mean, in which theorem are you stuck? My solution doesn't encounter double negation anywhere.

Comment: "I mean, in which theorem are you stuck?" - I thought that you know how from H and IHn deduce that `~ ~ even n'`. Can you tell me this? But your answer uses different approach. I printed your answer and will try to prove the theorems you gave. I read reflection part of IndProp.

Comment: @user4035 I added a link to the full solution.

Comment: I will look. Thank you.